# Is it possible to use the nvidia-driver only when gaming and nouveau at all other times? [Debian 9]

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, nouveau, graphic-card

Is it possible to switch between drivers during operating system run time? In particular I'd like use the FOSS [nouveau driver](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) for my nvidia graphics card at all times *except* when I'm doing GPU-intensive work / gaming.

If that is possible: how can I do that? (I'd like to switch to "gaming-mode" and back with a single command / click if possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 25 has [implemented several changes](https://negativo17.org/nvidia-driver-improvements-for-fedora-25/) on how to manage video card switch between Nvidia and Intel on the same laptop. But this is specific for this case: Optimus laptop with an Intel and a Nvidia card. Other distributions like Arch have imported those bits to their repos.

At the [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau_%26_nvidia-drivers_switching), there are some tricks on how switch nvidia modules on different kernels or same kernels with different profiles. Both cases require 2 separated entries on grub and a reboot is needed when you want to change modules.

**Answer**: There is no way to change during runtime the video card module being use and one module will require to blacklist the other and xorg changes will be needed based on the module.